# Помогите с сессиями в joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Приветствую Уважаемые! 
Не получается в джумле положить значение переменной в сессионную переменную и потом использовать это значение в другом файле, вообще делаю следующее:

в корневой директории лежит файл index.php, в нем я получаю значение из гет параметра следующим кодом:

```
$token = JRequest::getVar('_hm_token');
```

И это единственное, что у меня получается. Дальше ничего не получается:

В этом же index.php пытаюсь поместить значение переменной `$token` в сессию:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('_hm_token', $token);
```

Затем пытаюсь получить значение этой сессионной переменной в $tokenSess уже в другом файле, который лежит components/com_jshopping/controllers

```
 $tokenSess = $session->get("_hm_token");
```

чтобы отправить это значение в гет параметре через этот код

```
file_get_contents("http://track.lead-r.ru/?method=reportAction&transaction_id=".$order->order_number."&advertiser_id=15066&offer=15066A7lMr&token=".$token);
```

Подскажите как быть.

Comment: Для начала надо бы указать версию. Потом надо бы указать где именно вы делаете это все, в модели или контроллере.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как работать с подобными вещами.

В модели с которой вы работаете поидее должен быть метод `populateState`
Вот его пример для версии 3.0+

```
public function populateState() {

    $number = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.number', 'filter_number', '');
    $this->setState('filter.number', $number);


}
```

В этом методе мы получаем данные от текущего пользователя, и сохраняем.

Далее нам надо их получить в каком то методе, например в методе построения запроса к базе данных.

```
$filter_number = $this->getState('filter.number');
```

Во вьюхе мы можем получить наше сохраненное значение кодом

```
$this->state->get('filter.number');
```

Предварительно передав в методе `display` объект `state` в шаблон, например так.

```
$this->state = $this->get('State');
```